# Getting HTTP Status 500 ? Internal Server Error while upgrading tomcat 7 to 8

Tags: javascript, java, servlets, upgrade, tomcat8.5

Hope all are doing well..!
Am getting these errors while upgrading tomcat 7 to 8 And the tomcat is running on 8080 but my application is running on 8001.
I tried googling about this but am not getting any of those. All though most of them saying to install some lib files. But as per rules we can not download and put them in application as it is client application.
Here am attaching errors and logs.
Can anyone please help me to resolve this.

```
08-Sep-2020 08:15:26.687 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/8.5.57
08-Sep-2020 08:15:26.688 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Jun 30 2020 21:49:10 UTC
08-Sep-2020 08:15:26.688 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version number: 8.5.57.0
08-Sep-2020 08:15:26.689 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               SunOS
08-Sep-2020 08:15:26.689 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            5.10
08-Sep-2020 08:15:26.690 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          sparcv9
08-Sep-2020 08:15:26.691 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /opt/net/software/JDK/jdk1.8.0_77/jre
08-Sep-2020 08:15:26.691 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_77-b03
08-Sep-2020 08:15:26.692 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
08-Sep-2020 08:15:26.693 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /opt/net/web/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.57
08-Sep-2020 08:15:26.693 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /opt/net/web/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.57
08-Sep-2020 08:15:26.695 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/web/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.57/conf/logging.properties
08-Sep-2020 08:15:26.695 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
08-Sep-2020 08:15:26.696 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
08-Sep-2020 08:15:26.696 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
08-Sep-2020 08:15:26.697 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027
08-Sep-2020 08:15:26.698 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
08-Sep-2020 08:15:26.698 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/web/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.57
08-Sep-2020 08:15:26.699 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/web/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.57
08-Sep-2020 08:15:26.819 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/web/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.57/temp
08-Sep-2020 08:15:26.821 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The Apache Tomcat Native library which allows using OpenSSL was not found on the java.library.path: [.:/topnet/lib:/usr/jdk/packages/lib/sparcv9:/lib/64:/usr/lib/64]
08-Sep-2020 08:15:29.000 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
08-Sep-2020 08:15:29.055 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal Failed to initialize connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]
        org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
                at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:1077)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:552)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:848)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:639)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:662)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:302)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:472)
        Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
                at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
                at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
                at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
                at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
                at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:221)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:1118)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.init(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:222)
                at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:587)
                at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Protocol.init(AbstractHttp11Protocol.java:74)
                at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:1075)
                ... 13 more
08-Sep-2020 08:15:29.113 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-127.0.0.1-8009"]
08-Sep-2020 08:15:29.121 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal Failed to initialize connector [Connector[AJP/1.3-8009]]
        org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
                at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:1077)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:552)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:848)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:639)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:662)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:302)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:472)
        Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
                at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
                at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
                at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
                at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
                at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:221)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:1118)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.init(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:222)
                at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:587)
                at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:1075)
                ... 13 more
08-Sep-2020 08:15:29.581 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 6956 ms
08-Sep-2020 08:15:29.721 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
08-Sep-2020 08:15:29.722 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.57
08-Sep-2020 08:15:31.546 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
08-Sep-2020 08:15:32.004 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase.createSecureRandom Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [331] milliseconds.
08-Sep-2020 08:15:33.171 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
08-Sep-2020 08:15:33.343 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
08-Sep-2020 08:15:33.587 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
08-Sep-2020 08:15:34.185 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
08-Sep-2020 08:15:34.214 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [/opt/net/web/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.57/webapps/CTPDauClient.war]
08-Sep-2020 08:15:47.718 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
08-Sep-2020 08:15:54.769 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [/opt/net/web/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.57/webapps/CTPDauClient.war] has finished in [20,555] ms
08-Sep-2020 08:15:54.775 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/opt/net/web/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.57/webapps/ROOT]
08-Sep-2020 08:15:54.844 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/opt/net/web/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.57/webapps/ROOT] has finished in [69] ms
08-Sep-2020 08:15:54.845 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/opt/net/web/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.57/webapps/docs]
08-Sep-2020 08:15:54.905 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/opt/net/web/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.57/webapps/docs] has finished in [59] ms
08-Sep-2020 08:15:54.905 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/opt/net/web/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.57/webapps/examples]
08-Sep-2020 08:15:58.993 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/opt/net/web/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.57/webapps/examples] has finished in [4,088] ms
08-Sep-2020 08:15:58.995 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/opt/net/web/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.57/webapps/host-manager]
08-Sep-2020 08:15:59.105 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/opt/net/web/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.57/webapps/host-manager] has finished in [109] ms
08-Sep-2020 08:15:59.106 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/opt/net/web/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.57/webapps/manager]
08-Sep-2020 08:15:59.192 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/opt/net/web/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.57/webapps/manager] has finished in [85] ms
08-Sep-2020 08:15:59.193 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/opt/net/web/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.57/webapps/data]
08-Sep-2020 08:15:59.293 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/opt/net/web/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.57/webapps/data] has finished in [99] ms
08-Sep-2020 08:15:59.352 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 29765 ms
08-Sep-2020 08:15:59.358 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await StandardServer.await: create[localhost:8005]:
        java.net.BindException: Address already in use
                at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
                at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:387)
                at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:375)
                at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await(StandardServer.java:421)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.await(Catalina.java:776)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:722)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:342)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:473)
08-Sep-2020 08:15:59.361 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
08-Sep-2020 08:15:59.362 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-127.0.0.1-8009"]
08-Sep-2020 08:15:59.363 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stopInternal Stopping service [Catalina]
08-Sep-2020 08:15:59.565 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [CTPDauClient] appears to have started a thread named [Timer-0] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:552)
 java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
08-Sep-2020 08:15:59.638 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
08-Sep-2020 08:15:59.639 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
08-Sep-2020 08:15:59.641 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-127.0.0.1-8009"]
08-Sep-2020 08:15:59.641 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-127.0.0.1-8009"]
```

Thanks..!
Be Safe
[image: Application error]

Comment: Please provide the complete error logs to find the exact exception

Comment: Thank you so much for reply @Govind, Please help me to understand what mistake am doing here. I have modified the logs.. Can you please look into it..

Answer (score 1):

You already have something running on the same port. Probably the old version of your application. Refer to [How can you find out which process is listening on a port on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48198/how-can-you-find-out-which-process-is-listening-on-a-port-on-windows) for more info on how to figure out what is causing a conflict if it persists past a reboot of your machine.

Comment: am upgrading on Solaris server. Is it necessary to do reboot the machine after upgrading??

Comment: No idea. It never hurts though. This is the wrong place to ask.